# delay another key press after initial press for XXX ms

Tags: jquery, delay, keydown

I'm struggling with finding a way to add a short 200 ms delay after a keydown event.

This is to prevent someone from pressing the keys too fast one right after the other.

Here is the code currently:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
   if ($(e.target).is('input')) { e.stopPropogation(); }
   else if (e.keyCode == 37) { $(".pageback").click(); return false; }
   if (e.keyCode == 39) { $(".pagenext").click(); return false; } 
});
```

Comment: I can't answer this from my phone, it will take too long..but I would suggest you use $(document).on('keydown', function(){}); then in this function immediately unbind the keydown with $(document).off('keydown') followed by a setTimeout to add the keydown function again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prevent someone from pressing the key too quickly, and it's probably unwise/impossible to stop the message from coming.  however, you can track the time since the last key press and ignore the message if it's too soon:

```
var last_time = null;
$(document).keydown( function (e) {
    var now = new Date().getTime(),
        diff;
    if ($(e.target).is('input')) { 
        e.stopPropogation(); 
    } else if (e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 39) { 
        if( last_time != null ) {
            diff = now - last_time;
            if( diff < 200 ) {
                return false;   // do nothing
            }
        }
        last_time = now;
        if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
            $(".pageback").click(); 
            return false; 
        } if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
            $(".pagenext").click(); 
            return false;
        } 
    } 
});
```

Each time a key is pressed, the time since the last successful press is checked and if there has been enough delay, record the current time and carry on.  Otherwise, drop out.

Make sense?

Comment: ok .. this works, but also delays the text entered into an input area

Comment: Check first if the key press is one you are interested in -- not input -- and only ignore those messages.

Comment: OF COURSE! Time! This post is brilliant. I've been coding with so many asynchronous loops and set timer intervals recently I'd completely forgotten the basics..  Thank you for this post!  +1 .

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer;

$(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
   clearTimeout(timer);

   timer = setTimeout(function() {
       if ($(e.target).is('input')) { 
           e.stopPropogation(); 
       }else if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
           e.preventDefault();
           $(".pageback").click(); 
       }

       if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
           e.preventDefault();
           $(".pagenext").click();
       } 
   }, 200);
});
```

Use a simple timeout that clears when a key is pressed, that way the function won't execute if the user is typing faster than one key every 200ms.

Comment: Beast! There you go again ;)